# Draw chart with Float Js

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

Not getting points on chart only can see the X and Y Axis with digits.
My code of draw chart is as below

```
var length = 0;
var length1 = 0;
var dataXY = [];
length = allVenues.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   length1 = allVenues[i].length;
   for (var j = 0; j < length1; j++) {
    dataXY.push([allVenues[i][j].date, allVenues[i][j].price]);
   }
  }
  var result = {'label': 'chetan','data': dataXY};
  var options = {
       lines: {
        show: true
       },
       points: {
        show: true
       },
       xaxis: {
        tickDecimals: 0,
        tickSize: 1
       }
 };
 $.plot("#placeholder", JSON.stringify(result), options);
```

My JSON array output is like as below :

```
{"label":"abc","data":[["Feb 18, 2016 11:53:49 AM",12],["Feb 18, 2016 11:54:49 AM",30]]}
```

But still i am not able to draw a chart.
I'm not able to see the points on chart as well as not getting X-Axis data as per Dates of JSON Array.

Comment: assuming the you load you `json` data to `allVenues array`, how do you assign your `json` to `allVenues array`?

Comment: My allVenues array like as [{"item":"chocolate","price":12.0,"date":"Feb 18, 2016 11:53:49 AM"},{"item":"Mango","price":30.0,"date":"Feb 18, 2016 11:54:49 AM"}]
And i got the date and price from this array.

Comment: I think `flot` does not support `date and time` in this format. Please loot at it's documentation [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data)

Comment: Can you help me to convert the datetime format as per float js need from my datetime.
I'm using Java as a web language.